# jadira usertype PersistentLocalTimeAsString save LocalTime as tinyblob

Tags: jpa, jodatime

I have a JPA entity with a `org.joda.time.LocalTime` variable. I'm using Hibernate as JPA implementation and the jadira usertype to work with JodaTime classes so the definition of my variable is:

```
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalTimeAsString")
private LocalTime startTime;
```

When Hibernate creates the column for that variable, it use *tinyblob* instead of *varchar*, is it right?

If it is right, is there some class to save a `LocalTime` as *varchar*?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior happens if Hibernate can't find the user type for a column.

**1)** Use `TypeDef` to avoid typos

```
   @TypeDefs(
      {
         @TypeDef(name = "dateAsString", typeClass = org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalTimeAsString.class
      }  
   public class MyClass {  
      @Type(type="dateAsString")
      private LocalTime startTime;
```

if `PersistentLocalTimeAsString` is absent in you classpath, you will get compilation error.

**2)** Check that jadira-usertype is present in classpath.

**EDIT**

```
  @Type(type="dateAsString")
  @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR")
  private LocalTime startTime;
```

Comment: jadira-usertype is present 'cause I use it for other stuffs...but for the `LocalDate` or `DateTime` (classes that can be rappresented from a __database type__ it works fine...the problem is with thi `LocalTime` that can't be rappresented from a standard type

Comment: it works! But with this method I have to change it if I switch the database...Do you know if is it possible in another way?

Comment: @rascio I don't know why basic code works well with `LocalDate` and doesn't work with `LocalTime`, it's pazzle for me. I can propose only this way